# How to apply ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs with SharePoint path?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have a line:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="https://pmicloud-my.sharepoint.com/personal/yisaev_grintl_net/Documents/Book2.xlsm"
```

It returns an error:

> "Sorry we couldn't find path [path string here]. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Function `.SaveCopyAs` works with the path on a computer drive, but not with web site like SharePoint, when other options (`Workbooks.Open` and `Workbooks.SaveAs`) work with *the same path* to SharePoint.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but.... have you verified that link works?

Comment: You cannot **save** files to `http` or `https` with an app like Excel. You need to save them to your disk and **upload** them via browser (through the web-interface). There is no trick. This is the default behavior of  `http` or `https` protocols. Nothing wronng here.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, but as i understand meaning "save" I actually can - command  Workbooks.SaveAs with *this* path works properly - it creates copy of file with defined name in SharePoint location.

Comment: @urdearboy, yes, as I mentioned this link works with Workbooks. Open and Workbooks.SaveAs commands

Comment: Did you try it without `https://`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I just tried those typings: 
"//pmicloud-my.sharepoint.com/personal/yisaev_grintl_net/Documents/Book2.xlsm";
"pmicloud-my.sharepoint.com/personal/yisaev_grintl_net/Documents/Book2.xlsm"

Comment: I found this issue mentioned in 2013 here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/use-vba-savecopyas-to-save-to-sharepoint-url/8ddbfcd5-a237-4d2c-afb4-0b2d75143eaa
Still not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Well excel wants to save the file to a hard drive. Saving to an URL is not the same thing.

The SharePoint URL is a web interface displaying data on a network drive. If you have access to that network drive you can directly save the file there.

Otherwise you will have to save the file and upload it manually.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
I understand "save the file to a hard drive. Saving to an URL" is different. But issue not about saving to SharePoint - I already can do that by command Workbooks.SaveAs with the same link. The issue is the difference between Workbooks.SaveAs and Workbooks.SaveCopyAs - first works, second doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously Microsoft added some support for sharepoint over http(s), but it does not support the `.SaveCopyAs` method:

You can vote for this feature here:
[Improve *Workbook.SaveCopyAs VBA method - support SharePoint / OneDrive](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/34530937-improve-workbook-savecopyas-vba-method-support)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out other sources of info!