# SaveAs function working but not SaveCopyAs

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to save a copy of a file under the name of a cell specified in the active sheet. The functionality of my VBA code works fine with SaveAs, but not with SaveCopyAs. I need it to save a copy of the file and not rename the actual file, since the file is being reused every month. The file name (Initiative Dashboard - Developing Careers) needs to remain the same.

Code is listed below:

```
Dim file_name As String

file_name = Workbooks("Initiative Dashboard - Developing Careers.xlsm").Worksheets("Initiative Dashboard").Range("M3")

ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "https://heathrowportal.sharepoint.com/teams/ChangetheBusiness/Shared%20Documents/General/2.%20Master%20Docs/Initiative%20Monthly%20Dashboard/" & file_name _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

I have tried it with SaveAs and the functionality works perfectly, saving the file into the sharepoint location, however, it is renaming the actual file and thus the code cannot run more than once.

Comment: Please provide the `SaveCopyAs` code that isn't working.

Comment: Not nice workaround: Load again the previously saved original one.

Comment: Dim file_name As String

file_name = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("M3")

ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:= _
        "https://heathrowportal.sharepoint.com/teams/ChangetheBusiness/Shared%20Documents/General/2.%20Master%20Docs/Initiative%20Monthly%20Dashboard/" & file_name _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Comment: [`SaveCopyAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas) has *one* parameter, not three. Remove `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False`. You can't change the `FileFormat` with `SaveCopyAs` either... which makes sense, a "copy" is exactly that, no changes.

Comment: Thank you, however when I try that, it states it cannot locate the given sharepoint link...And as soon as I change it from SaveAsCopy to SaveAs without hanging anything, then it works perfectly. Is it perhaps because the original is not located in this filepath?

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352883/)